# How can I Parcelize data class contain list from another data class? in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I try to Parcelize this data class but the problem is contain a list from another data class

```
@Parcelize
data class Data(
    val alternative_titles: List<String>,
    val authors: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val chapters: List<Chapter> = emptyList(),
    val description: String ="",
    val genres: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val last_updated: String ="",
    val rating: Double =0.0,
    val rating_count: Int= 0,
    val status: String ="",
    val title: String ="",
    val views_count: String =""
): Parcelable
```

The error in line chapters:
[image]

and the other data class

```
data class Chapter(
    val id: String,
    val number: Int,
    val title: String,
    val uploaded_at: String,
    val url: String,
    val views_count: Int
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the @Parcelize and Parcelable also to the other data class. so like

```
@Parcelize
data class Chapter(
    val id: String,
    val number: Int,
    val title: String,
    val uploaded_at: String,
    val url: String,
    val views_count: Int
): Parcelable
```